# WordBoundary issue in StringReplace

Tags: string-manipulation

Why does the following `StringReplace` pattern match:

```
StringReplace["blah *hello* blah", ("*" ~~ ShortestMatch[str__] ~~ "*") :> 
    ("<u>" <> str <> "</u>")]
(* blah <u>hello</u> blah *)
```

but not when bracketing the pattern with `WordBoundary`:

```
StringReplace["blah *hello* blah", (WordBoundary ~~ "*" ~~ 
    ShortestMatch[str__] ~~ "*" ~~ WordBoundary) :> ("<u>" <> str <> "</u>")]
(* "blah *hello* blah" *)
```

Comment: btw, `ShortestMatch` is now superseded by `Shortest`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because what you want to match is the `Whitespace` not the `Wordboundary`. In fact, you really don't need `WordBoundary` because your "*hello*" is surrounded by `Whitespace`. This means, if the word you want to match, happens to be at the end of a line, `WordBoundary` would prevent the match. Therefore, the only thing you need is `WhiteSpace`

```
StringReplace["blah *hello* blah", 
 (Whitespace ~~ "*" ~~ Shortest[str__] ~~ "*" ~~ Whitespace) :> 
  (" <u>" <> str <> "</u> ")]
```

If you realy are keen to use it, you have to take care of the `Whitespace` too

```
StringReplace["blah *hello* blah", 
 (WordBoundary ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
    "*" ~~ Shortest[str__] ~~ "*" ~~ 
  Whitespace ~~ WordBoundary) 
 :> (" <u>" <> str <> "</u> ")]
```

Comment: No need to use `WordBoundary`. Try `(Whitespace ~~ "*" ~~ Shortest[str__] ~~ "*" ~~ Whitespace)`

Comment: Ok great, thanks for all the answers and comments

Comment: @DavidCarraher I know. Look at my first code block. I just wanted to make clear how *it would work* with `WordBoundary`..

Comment: You might want to mention this in your answer.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I thought *Whitespace not the Wordboundary.* in my first sentence was enought. Let me make it clearer.